# OAuth with DropboxAPI without manually copying url to authorize

Tags: java, oauth, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am trying to create an application (in java) to monitor files in Dropbox (File added, File deleted, File modified... etc).  I can get my application to generate a https url using the DropboxAPI.  The problem is that I have to manually copy and paste the url into a browser, log in on that browser and hit allow.  Once they do this once I can easily store the information so they do not have to redo this process.  Unfortunately the program does not stay running up and is frequently restarted.

My hope is that it is possible to get past this step since I will have access to the users Dropbox password and username already in the application.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

When you say "easily store this information", what information are you storing and where are you storing it?

Once you finish the OAuth flow, save the access token somewhere persistent (like to a file or to a database).  That way, if your program gets restarted you just load the access token and use that without re-doing the OAuth flow.

In the official Dropbox Java SDK, load your saved access token and then call [`setAccessTokenPair`](https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-java-sdk-1.3.1-docs/com/dropbox/client2/session/AbstractSession.html#setAccessTokenPair%28com.dropbox.client2.session.AccessTokenPair%29).

Answer (score 0):

I have written a simple program to upload files to dropbox server, for backup purpose.
If you are looking for an implementation . You may check out the code via https://github.com/Jintian/dropbox.